# Pass variables between modules

Tags: python, search, module, return, parameter-passing

I have a tkinter gui that has a basic entry box and search button. That searches a list in a module named SearchList.py

**Main.py**

```
from tkinter import *
from SearchList import *
root = Tk()
Output = []

def search():
    search = e.get()
    Output= SearchList.go(search)

#search bar
e= Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

#search button
doneButton = Button(root, text="Search", width= 10, command=search).grid(row=0, column=4)


#arranges output in a 5 column rectangle
r, c = (1,0)

c_limit= 5

for thing in Output:
    myButton = Button(root, text=thing,height=5, width=25, borderwidth=3, padx=10).grid(row=r,column=c)
    c+=1
    if c == c_limit:
        c=0
        r+=1


root.mainloop()
```

This lets me input what I want to search and sends it to the Searchlist.py module and the output (matches from list) is arranged in a rectangle.

**SearchList.py**

```
Output = []


def main(search):
    for x in range(list):
         if list[x]== search:
              Output.append(list[x])
         else:
              continue
    Output.sort
    return Output


def go(search):
    with client:
        client.loop.run_until_complete(main(search))
```

But it keeps returning `None`.
Also I know I must be calling the module incorrectly- just not sure how.

Comment: You are probably just missing the `return` in `return client.loop.run_until_complete(main(search))` in `SearchList.go`.

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, very,very hard not to use global variables.

Comment: @Erich That was my problem, but the list is not being displayed in the tkinter grid for some reason?

Comment: You are missing a `global Output` at the very beginning of `search`.

Comment: Oh I see. Answer with the reformatted code and I''ll accept it

Comment: I did post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two minor issues here. First you are missing a `return` in `SearchList.py`:

```
def go(search):
    with client:
        # insert return here
        return client.loop.run_until_complete(main(search))
```

Second, you don't write to the correct variable in `search`:

```
def search():
    # use global keyword to reference global variable Output
    global Output
    search = e.get()
    Output= SearchList.go(search)
```